# How to prove that $n^n \times n! \times (\sqrt{2})^{n}\le (2n)! $

Tags: limits, inequality, factorial

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

> Q: How to prove that ($n \in \mathbb{N}$)
>   $$n^n \times n! \times (\sqrt{2})^{n}\le  (2n)! $$

I try

$\log(n^n \times n! \times (\sqrt{2})^{n})\le  \log(2n)!$

$\to$

$n\log n +\log n!+ n\log \sqrt{2} \le  \log(2n)!$

$\to$

$n(\log n +\log \sqrt{2}) \le  \log(n+1)+ \log(n+2)+\cdots+ \log (2n)$

And then?

Comment: Aren't you already done with your last step? "Observe": $\log \sqrt{2} < 1$. In fact I find your approach the most immediate one of the suggested solutions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove that for all $1 \leq k  \leq n$ you have
$$2n^2 \leq (n+k)(2n+1-k)$$

Comment: pleas more explain about $2n^2 \leq (n+k)(2n+1-k)$

Comment: @N. S. it might be a good idea to explain in a little more depth how you jumped from the OP's statement to this one in your answer, and how it can solve their question.

Comment: @Young Cancel $n!$ from both sides to get a simpler inequality. Also, when you have a product of consecutive integers, if you start multiplying first with last, second first with second last,... as you move towards the middle the product increases...

Answer (score 1):

Induction will do the trick if you're willing to prove a bunch of base cases (specifically, as we'll see, for $n=1$ to $13$) and if you know that $(1+{1\over n})^n\lt e$ for all $n$ and $\sqrt2e\approx3.844231\lt4-{1\over7}$. The crucial induction step is

$$\begin{align}
(n+1)^{n+1}(n+1)!(\sqrt2)^{n+1}
&=\sqrt2\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n(n+1)^2n^nn!(\sqrt2)^n\\
&=\sqrt2\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n(n+1)^2(2n)!\quad\text{by the induction hypothesis}\\
&\lt\left(4-{1\over7}\right)(n+1)^2(2n)!\\
&\lt\left(4-{2\over n+1}\right)(n+1)^2(2n)!\quad\text{if }n\ge13\\
&=(4n+2)(n+1)(2n)!\\
&=2(2n+1)(n+1)(2n)!\\
&=(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)!\\
&=(2n+2)!
\end{align}$$

There might be some nice way to avoid the plethora of base cases here -- I'm not thrilled with the idea of having to verify the inequality all the way up to $n=13$ (and, admittedly, have not done so myself) -- but I don't see any obvious alternative. Maybe someone else does.

Answer (score 0):

I would say your best bet is [Proof by Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction).

First note the two sides are *never equal* unless you make the incorrect assumption that $0^0=1$.

Base case of $n=1$:
$$LHS\to 1\cdot1\cdot(\sqrt2)^1=\sqrt2$$
$$RHS\to 2!=2>\sqrt2$$
so true for $n=1$

Inductive Step: Assume true for $n=k$:
$$k^k\cdot k!\cdot(\sqrt2)^k<(2k)!$$
And use to show true for $n=k+1$

So prove using the above statement that:
$$(k+1)^{k+1}\cdot(k+1)!\cdot(\sqrt2)^{k+1}<(2k+2)!$$
It may help to re-write it as:
$$(k+1)(k+1)^{k}+(k+1)(k!)+\sqrt2(\sqrt2)^k<(2k+2)(2k+1)(2k)!$$

Comment: I was composing an induction-based answer when you poasted this, but found my approach requires a boatload of base cases, not just $n=1$. Can you get the relevant induction inequality to kick in from the get go?